# What is the difference between missing the point and the false cause fallacy?

Tags: logic

What is different between missing the point and false cause fallacy.

Can someone give examples that demonstrate the difference and distinguish them.

In some introduction to logic books, these informal logic terms had been introduced, but it's not clear to me what is different.

Answer (score 2):

missing the point is proving something different than what was sought.

false cause is asserting a predecessor statement that is not required to arrive at the desired conclusion.